# which java classes are being loaded by my program at run-time?

Tags: java, class

I am using Netbeans. How to know all the classes of a package(say lucene, which I am using) that are actually being used/loaded by my program. I want to keep my distribution small, therefore remove all the classes that are not being used at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netbeans, I can't help you with. However, the core JRE can answer your question.

```
java -verbose:class ...
```

will print the entire list.

Or you could look into Apache/Maven jxr and use the API.